# InDesign CC: Text won't go to top of frame (checked all other issues)

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, alignment, paragraph-styles, text-wrap

I'm dealing with an issue where, when adjusting an existing text box (i.e. font and leading resizing), the text will not sit at the top of the frame where it was before. I've chased the following potential causes:

- Looked for hidden characters
- Made sure frame alignment is set to "Top"
- Confirmed there is no inset spacing
- Ignored text wrap
- Confirmed default baseline settings
- Confirmed there is no set paragraph spacing
- Confirmed default paragraph rules / no special styles
- Confirmed default character styles / no special styles
- Confirmed that baseline/grid alignment is turned off

I've noticed this issue in several different documents, and while I can fix it by creating a new text box and formatting from scratch, that is not the most time-efficient solution. Anyone else have any bright ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The "Auto-Size" feature could also affect this. <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> your text box and check the "Auto-Size" tab. Play with this and see if there's any change.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted 2 years ago but I have been noticing this problem with a client's template lately. I found it. It is hidden in Text Frame Options > Baseline Options. **First Baseline** should be set to "Ascent" and not "Leading" as mine was. This fixed it for me!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. Playing around with the text frame options did not help. I found out that the problem has to do with the paragraph style.
Open Paragraph Style Options and go to Indents and Spacing. There is box called "Align to Grid". Choose "None".

Best regards from
Geir

Answer (score 0):

Textframe Options > Baseline Options > fist baseline > Offset:Cap-height